# Best way to refactor this C code? CS50 - mario.c (more)

Tags: c, for-loop, cs50

So Im taking the cs50 course and solving the mario.c more from pset 1

I actually solved it with 3 for loops, but I wanted to refactor it with just 2 loops and i came up with this code that gives the following solution for "height: 5"

```html
Result:
    #  #
   ##  ##
  ###  ###
 ####  ####
#####  #####
```

```js
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   
    int side = 5;
    int max = side + 2;

    for (int i = 1 ; i <= side ; i++)
    {
      int j = 1;
      while(j != max+1)
      {
        if(j <= side-i)
        {
        printf(" ");
        j++;
        }
        else if(j > side-i && j < side+1)
        {
        printf("#");
        j++;
        }
        else if(j == side+1)
        {
        printf("  ");
        j++;
        } 
        else 
        {
        printf("#");
        j++;
        }
      }
    max++;
    printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Id like to know if you guys can show me a more elegant solution since I think this is way too... repetitive.

Also, is it possible to use switch case instead of so many else if? Tried to do it but code did not take booleans for j :(

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Why tag this with Javascript if it's C??

Comment: Sorry misclicked wrong tag

Comment: If the code is working you can post on [codereview.se]. Remember to read their help center before asking.

Comment: You should not include 'thank' in posts. See this meta post: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know an upper limit for the height, you can do it in a single loop.

Like:

```
int main(void) {
    char s[] = "#############################################";
    char f[32];

    int n = 5;  // height

    sprintf(f, "%%%ds  %%s", n);   // Create a format string like "%5s  %s"
    char* p = s + strlen(s) - 1;   // Let p point to the last char in s

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)         // Loop n times
    {
        printf(f, p, p);
        printf("\n");
        p--;                       // Increase the number of # that p points to
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note: If you don't know an upper limit for the height, you can still use this approach but then `s` must be dynamic allocated.

Comment: The upper limit for the height should be 24 but holy cow! thank you! you definately answered my question and I will be studying this answer, i owe u a beer and a pizza. :)